# How to install OutLook Lan Messenger?

Tags: installation, instant-messaging

I try to install OutLook Lan Messenger (OM) but could not install properly.
I tried these steps:

1. download OM from [Outlook Messenger official site](http://www.outlookmessenger.com/OM/lan_messenger_download.aspx) for Linux / Ubuntu.
2. try to install from the terminal but cannot completed.

Please give me some idea behind this.

**Edit:**

Installation was complete by following below answers. Not working, instead of LAN IP set? Tell Me other strategy how is it work when LAN IP set?

Comment: plz post your errors

Comment: Have you installed openjdk6?

Comment: yeah, i have already installed openjdk6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have openjdk6 installed, do the following:

1. Download Outlook Messenger from the website.
2. Go to your download folder, right click on "outlookmessenger7.jar" and select "Extract here".
3. Go in the new "OM" folder.
4. Right click on "OutlookMessenger.jar", select Properties.
5. Go to the "Permissions" tab, check "Allow executing file as program". Close that window.
6. Right click on "OutlookMessenger.jar", select "Open with OpenJDK Java 6 Runtime".

There you go! (There is no need for installing, and no need for the terminal.)

Comment: ...it works fine...but i have to try to communicate with all users need to communicate within our office, using LAN only.. How to fix this?        I have try this:>> Network>> Link server ip address(***.***.**.***). but could not works fine.

Comment: I think it is better to open a new question for this, as it is not related to the installation any more. Furthermore, consider marking this answer as accepted if it helped you, since it may also help further users.

Comment: installation complete but OM could not work proper to communicate with other friend. I already mention, I proper set my LAN IP but how is it not working? why?

Comment: As I said, please open a new question for this, Google_Android_Lovers.